# Vectorizing LU factorization using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

so I am trying to implement a LU factorization function without using the built in functions available to me.

The implementations I have see have all been with nested for loops, and as we all know those are very nasty to look at. Hopefully I will have an implementation that is vectorized with numpy.

This is what i have so far:

```py
def lu_factorize(matrix):
    w, h = matrix.shape
    L = np.eye(w)
    for k in range(w-1):
        U = np.eye(w)
        U[k+1:, k] = -(matrix[k+1, k] / matrix[k, k])
        L += -np.tril(U, -1)
        matrix = np.matmul(U, matrix)
    return matrix, L
```

As you can see in each iteration we are reseting the U matrix and multiplying by the orignal matrix, and for L matrix we are just adding to the orignal.

Is there any meaningful way to relieve me of the for loop and gain speedups?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Each next iteration depends on the previous iteration result through `matrix`. This loop is strictly sequential.